# Capture a specific value from a json in an alert

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I'm working on an angular project with php. I've encode the php results in json and in the json i'm trying to capture a spefic field `(fname)` data from the json but finding it hard to do

```
$http.get('http://localhost/vivalooks/app_ion/feeds.php').success(function(data){
       console.log(data);
       $scope.feeds=data;
       alert(data.fname)


})
```

response from console

```
[{"fname":"Benjamin","lname":"Osei","up_ans":"Changed","exs":"new","total":"1"}]
```

Comment: Try open `http://localhost/vivalooks/app_ion/feeds.php` in your browser & print the output . Then , we can guess

Comment: have you tried [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: try  alert  :  `alert(typeof data+Array.isArray(data))` instead of `alert(data.fname)`.. Give me the output  ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI, 
 
it only says objecttrue

Comment: can you copy the exact return result of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: questiion is editted and the cosole response has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so

```
alert(data[0].fname)
```

NOT

```
alert(data.fname)
```

because , `data` is an array .

---

Because, when i requested in comments to print the output of `alert(typeof data+Array.isArray(data))` , you wrote : `objecttrue` : it means :

- object : Object=> can be literal , array, something else
- true  :  IS Array

---

## Extra :

Yo loop through  all `fname` , just, do this :

```
alert(data.map((e)=>e.fname).join(','));
```